# Best way to capture output from system command to a text file?

Tags: perl, shell, system, exec, io-redirection

I’m trying to capture output from using Perl’s `system` function to execute and redirect a system command’s ouptut to a file, but for some reason I’m not getting the whole output.

I’m using the following method:

```
system("example.exe >output.txt");
```

What’s wrong with this code, or is there an alternative way of doing the same thing?

Comment: where example.exe is a win32 console application

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Same as [MVS's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7799045#7799174), but modern and safe.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open (my $file, '>', 'output.txt') or die "Could not open file: $!";
my $output = `example.exe`; 
die "$!" if $?; 
print $file $output;
```

easier

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use autodie;

open (my $file, '>', 'output.txt');
print $file `example.exe`;
```

if you need both STDOUT and STDERR

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use autodie;
use Capture::Tiny 'capture_merged';

open (my $file, '>', 'output.txt');
print $file capture_merged { system('example.exe') };
```

Comment: I really cannot imagine why you would do all that, not even the first. And you still missed stderr.

Comment: First of all, this post began as a comment on the outdated practices in MVS's answer. Second I didn't do "all that", just checked what I should. Third if it is "all that" it just shows how nice `autodie` is. And fourth, how did I miss `STDERR`? Fifth, yes you can do it all with shell redirection, but Frank already did that, and I don't trust the Windows shell/ I don't have a windows computer to test anything on so lean on solved wheels.

Comment: @tchrist, Other than shell redirection, how would you do it?

Comment: Just to clarify, my answer was meant to be a code snippet just like in the question.  I didn't include strict or warnings because I assume he already has them.  My mistake about `or` vs. `||`, though.  Either one works here, but `or` is better for error checking, so I'll edit that.  I was coding in PHP at the time and got my wires crossed a little.  As for the rest, TMTOWTDI. :)

Comment: @MVS, no, its the lexical filehandle, the 3-arg open and checking the status of the backtick execution that I care about. don't care about the `or`, and I always put in `strict` and `warnings` for any newbies present

Comment: Perl knows about `2>` stuff even on Micosoft-ridden ports. Ilya put it in. And even he didn’t, we certainly know how to dup our descriptors correctly.

Comment: @Joel I would simply use Perl’s `system` for what it was designed for, is how I would do it. It’s smarter than you might think, and really, if it *isn’t* good enough to handle so basic an operation as this one, then there is a Problem that needs fixing. `if (system("proggie >outfile 2>&1") != 0) { ... }`

Comment: @tchrist, I do not know the shell commands well. Franks answer already had that so, I'm not sure why my answer is worth your ire. Further it seems that other people have the same concerns/lack-of-shell-knowledge as I have http://stackoverflow.com/q/7809740/468327 so I think its worth knowing a second way of accomplishing this.

Comment: Capture::Tiny has now been extended with Capture::Tiny::Extended,
you can have 
($out, $err, $retval ) = capture { system( "run system command" ) }
check out http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/45/idpl/21405428/numer/3/nazwa/Capture::Tiny::Extended for more information

Comment: @DataGuru Capture::Tiny::Extended seems to be abandoned since 2011 and most of its features are already in original Capture::Tiny.

Answer (score 10):

Redirecting the output with plain > will only catch STDOUT. If you also want to catch STDERR, use 2>&1:

```
perl -e 'system("dir blablubblelel.txt >out.txt 2>&1");'
```

For more details, see [Perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=4913)

Comment: this is not answer. this method use asker but wants another.

Answer (score 1):

When you want recirect output permanently, you can do:

```
#redirect STDOUT before calling other functions
open STDOUT,'>','outputfile.txt' or die "can't open output";
system('ls;df -h;echo something');  #all will be redirected.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try having Perl capture the output instead:

```
open(FILE, ">output.txt") or die "Could not open file: $!";
print FILE `example.exe`;
close(FILE);
```

Comment: this doesn't redirect output for for commands called by 'system' function. This workaround has big but. When 'example.exe' generate very big output, you can easly overflow available memory.

Answer (score 0):

I find this way a very nice way to do it:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Capture::Tiny::Extended 'capture';

my ($out, $err, $ret) = capture {
    system 'example.exe';
};
$ret = $ret >> 8;

print "OUT: $out\n";
print "ERR: $err\n";
print "RET: $ret\n";
```

Thanks DWGuru for commenting on [Capture::Tiny::Extended](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny::Extended). :-)

Comment: Capture::Tiny::Extended seems to be abandoned since 2011 and most of its features are already in original Capture::Tiny (last updated in 2018), so better use this one.

Answer (score -1):

This works:

In C code, you could have the below line to capture the required output:

```
system("example.exe > \"output.txt\"");
```

Comment: This example merely adds quotation marks around output.txt. Quotes aren't necessary for a file name without spaces. Its effect is identical to that of the question.