# How can I catch a "failed to decode JSON" error message in Perl?

Tags: json, perl, load-testing, stderr

So I am trying to ***load*** test a REST API which returns a JSON value.

To do that I am creating multiple instances of the perl script.

The Perl script basically calls that URL, and tries to `decode_json`. Obviously when substantial load is generated, it fails.

Now the problem I face is- An error is displayed on command prompt but does not write that error message in a file.

The error message is

`malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "Can't connect to 209...") at json_load_test.pl line 39.`

In all the three attempts below line 39 refers to:

```
decode_json($actual_response);
```

I am simply running the script on the command prompt as:

```
perl json_load_test.pl >> logs/output.txt
```

**I EXPECT THE ERROR MESSAGE TO BE WRITTEN IN "output.txt"**

My three *failed* attempts are as follows.

#### Attempt 1:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->timeout(3);    
$ua->env_proxy;        
my $response = $ua->get("http://$j_env/jobs/all.json?status=active");
my $actual_response=$response->decoded_content;
decode_json($actual_response);
if ($? == -1)
{print "\n Failed to execute: $!\n"; }
```

#### Attempt 2:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->timeout(3);    
$ua->env_proxy;        
my $response = $ua->get("http://$j_env/jobs/all.json?status=active");
my $actual_response=$response->decoded_content;
my $perl_scalar= decode_json($actual_response);
if ($perl_scalar)
{ok(1,"For process $u2 inside counter $counter ");}
else
{ok(0,"FAILED!!! process $u2 inside counter $counter");}
```

#### Attempt 3:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->timeout(3);    
$ua->env_proxy;        
my $response = $ua->get("http://$j_env/jobs/all.json?status=active");
my $actual_response=$response->decoded_content;
decode_json($actual_response) or die "FAILED!!!!";
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It looks like your error message is coming from stderr, not stdout.  Thus,

```
perl json_load_test.pl >> logs/output.txt 2>> logs/errors.txt
```

Or something to that effect.  If you want both in one file:

```
perl json_load_test.pl 2>&1 >> logs/output.txt
```

**EDIT:**

If for some reason you wanted to trap the error in the perl and send it to stdout, you could:

```
eval {
  decode_json($actual_response);
  1;
} or do {
  my $e = $@;
  print "$e\n";
};
```

**EDIT2:**

As daxim points out in the edit notes, Try::Tiny may be simpler:

```
use Try::Tiny;
try {
  decode_json($actual_response);
} catch {
  print "$_\n";
};
```

Comment: in Unix, that's `perl json_load_test.pl > logs/output.txt 2>&1 logs/errors.txt`

Comment: @Arkadiy In fairness, the OP didn't specify whether they were using Unix or an operating system I just made up.

Comment: Thing is, 1>2 will create a file named "2" in current directory :)

Comment: Thank you Thom for your response, I opted for your second solution. Using that the error messages stopped displaying on the console, but still does not write into the logs/output.txt file. ALSO, can i control the text that will be written in?

Comment: Well I apologize for the lack of information, I am indeed using Unix to run that command

Comment: @perlnewbie If you want to control what the error message is, you can either 1) rewrite the JSON module to output a different error message (not recommended), or 2) use the `eval` method I posted and print something else instead of `$e`.

Comment: Yes, the eval method is a much simpler solution for me. You answered my question perfectly. thanks.

Comment: @perlnewbie note edits - the style I had in there originally had some issues - you can check out http://search.cpan.org/dist/Perl-Critic/lib/Perl/Critic/Policy/ErrorHandling/RequireCheckingReturnValueOfEval.pm for details

Comment: `eval {
  decode_json($actual_response);
  1;
} or do {
  my $e = $@;
  print "$e\n";
}`

should be

`eval {
  decode_json($actual_response);
  1;
} or do {
  my $e = $@;
  print "$e\n";
};`