# Keep program running after decode_json() error

Tags: json, perl

decode_json() terminates my program when the argument is not valid json. How can I keep my program running and handle the error?

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use JSON;

my      $json='<html></html>';
my      $ticker=decode_json($json);
print $json;
```

The last print shall be executed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I catch a "failed to decode JSON" error message in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809740/how-can-i-catch-a-failed-to-decode-json-error-message-in-perl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a prime example of a time to wrap the `decode_json()` in a [try catch block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342875/how-to-properly-use-the-try-catch-in-perl-that-error-pm-provides).

Doing so will enable you to continue execution, and it also opens up the door to handle the error so that you can have a specific response to the cases where the error occurs.