# Perl - impdp from perl

Tags: perl

I am not able to re-direct the output of impdp command from system () perl to a file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$a="impdp GLS_UCELL_80TC5_DEV/comverse directory=DUMP_DIR_1028704 dumpfile=ACCESS_REGION_VALUES.dmp CONTENT=data_only";
system("$a 1>t.tmp");
```

However, upon changing the system command to `system("$a 2>t.tmp")`, t.tmp gets created.

I want to understand why the re-direction 1>t.tmp not working in my case.

Comment: What happened with `1`? Was the file created, but empty?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to capture output from system command to a text file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799045/best-way-to-capture-output-from-system-command-to-a-text-file)

Comment: Yes the file created but empty

Comment: Your command is writing output to `STDERR`.

Comment: Yes it is writing to stderr but not stdout .. Why is that so?

Comment: Because that's how it was written.

Answer (score 0):

`1>t.tmp` (or just `>t.tmp`) redirects STDOUT. Anything printed to STDOUT will end up in the file.

`2>t.tmp` redirects STDERR. Anything printed to STDERR will end up in the file.

You want to capture what your program writes to STDERR, so you need to use the latter, or `>t.tmp 2>&1` which redirects both.

Comment: Thanks for your comments:) I dont need to use 2>t.tmp when I execute impdp from a shell script. 1>.t.tmp just works fine. I m not able to understand why do i need to write 2>t.tmp from a perl prog and why not 1>t.tmp as above

Comment: As I already said, you want to capture what the program writes to STDERR, so you need to redirect STDERR, and that's done using `2>`